# Adding user input text to .txt file

Tags: java, text

I'm trying to update a .txt file containing a list of movies and some information by asking the user said information.
The file is organized like this:

```
0000-Movie Title Goes Here-9.99-ClientID
0001-Same thing here-9.99-CLIENTID2
```

And so on.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    BufferedWriter output = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("movies.txt", true));
    System.out.println("Inserte numero de la pelicula:\n");
    String pelNum = CTeclado.ReadString();
    System.out.println("Inserte el titulo de la pelicula:\n");
    String pelName = CTeclado.ReadString();
    System.out.println("Inserte el precio de la pelicula:\n");
    String pelPrice = CTeclado.ReadString();
    output.append(pelNum + "-" + pelName + "-" + pelPrice + "-null");
    output.close();
    ReadM();
    System.out.println("Pelicula agregada!\n");
    MainMenu();
```

(The CTeclado thing is used for reading input)
This compiles without error, however, there's no change in the actual file....
What's wrong with my code?

Comment: Is the file you're trying to modify in the same folder as the jar file? If you only specify the file name without a path, java assumes that the file is in the same folder as the source code that is being executed. Also, please conform to java naming conventions. Variable and method names begin with a lowercase letter.

Comment: Yes it is, as a matter of fact, I've tried putting the whole filepath on the field and get the same result. I'm aware, the CTeclado class and its methods were passed on to me by someone else, and it's a lengthy class, I'll edit it later.

Comment: Oops! I completely just missed the fact that you're using the wrong method! Use the [`write()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write(java.lang.String,%20int,%20int)) method to write things to the file: `output.write("stuff goes here");`

Comment: Excellent! Tried that, then modified my own code a bit (still using .append) and got it to work as well. Both are viable solutions =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try the below code

```
 PrintStream output = new PrintStream(new File("movies.txt"));
 output.append(pelNum + "-" + pelName + "-" + pelPrice + "-null").append("\n");
```

Comment: This actually worked better in the end since my delete method always leaves a blank line at the end of the file. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Using `output.write("\n" + "stuff goes here)` worked just like @fireshadow52 said.
`output.append("\n" + "stuff")` also worked, had to make sure the .txt file ended exactly at the end of the line (not on a new line)